# Collecting data from a Multi-Dimensional Array?

Tags: javascript

If I had something like this:

```
var multi_array = [[1,1], [2,2]];
```

how could i pull data from the second array in the multi-array and maybe log it to the console.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you couldn't since you effectively have a syntax error.  You can't use `-` in a variable name.  But looking past that...

```
var multi_array = [[1,1], [2,2]];
console.log(multi_array[1]); // Outputs:  [2,2]
```

The first array is at `multi_array[0]`, and the second at `multi_array[1]`.  Suppose you wanted to get the second element in the second array:

```
console.log(multi_array[1][1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you don't really mean the second array, but the second value of the inner array. Use `map` to pick only special values from the inner arrays:

```
var ar = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]];

var new_ar = ar.map(function(inner_ar){
   return inner_ar[1];
});

console.log(new_ar); // [2, 4, 6]
```